# SWIG / C# : namespace and templates

Tags: c#, c++, namespaces, swig

I have a C++ library and wish to use SWIG to generate a nice wrapper around, for this, I have created the following SWIG interface file, but I got some issues:

1 - No C# namespace is generated

2 - The C++ Expected class is complex, I wish to create my own wrapper (partial class by example) in C#, all I need is that SWIG generates the skeleton. I will provide the remainder of the implementation myself. Is there a way to do this ? (I have checked the doc. but it is unclear). Also, the C# class has to be a generic class, so instead of Expected_Void I will have Expected etc...

3 - Is there a way to force SWIG to generate an interface instead of a class ? (For the C++ class IViewHandle)

Here is my .i file

```
%module sdk
%{
  #include "../include/sdk/core/Expected.hpp"
  #include "../include/luciadsdk/view/IViewHandle.hpp"
  #include "../include/sdk/view/IViewContext.hpp"
  #include "../include/sdk/view/ViewContext.hpp"
%}

%include <windows.i>

%nodefaultctor;

//--------------------------------------------------
// Expected<T>
//--------------------------------------------------

%nspace sdk::core;
namespace sdk {
namespace core {

  template<typename T>
  class Expected
  {
  public:
  };

  %template(Expected_Int)   Expected<int>;
  %template(Expected_Float) Expected<float>;
  %template(Expected_Bool)  Expected<bool>;
  %template(Expected_Void)  Expected<void>;

} }

//--------------------------------------------------
// IViewHandle
//--------------------------------------------------

%nspace sdk::view;
namespace sdk {
namespace view {

  class IViewHandle
  {
  public:
  };

} }

//--------------------------------------------------
// IViewContext
//--------------------------------------------------

%nspace sdk::view;
namespace sdk {
namespace view {

  class IViewContext
  {
  public:

    virtual sdk::Expected<void> setHandle(const IViewHandle& handle) = 0;

    virtual void invalidate() = 0;

    protected:
      IViewContext() = default;
      ~IViewContext() = default;
  };

} }

//--------------------------------------------------
// ViewContext
//--------------------------------------------------

%nspace sdk::view;
namespace sdk {
namespace view {

  class ViewContext : public IViewContext
  {
  public:
    ViewContext();
    ~ViewContext();

    sdk::Expected<void> setHandle(const IViewHandle& handle) override;

    void invalidate() override;
  };

} }

%clearnodefaultctor;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For the namespaces, the only way I found to generate them in C# is to add the [-namespace](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#CSharp_commandline) to the swig wrapper.

Like:

> swig -namespace MyC#Namespace.MyC#OhterNamespace myfile.i

2. I think you find it thanks to the other post.
3. I never found a solution for the interfaces, since it is quite different in C# and C++,

Comment: Yes, I know for the namespace, the problem is that every class must have its own namespace ! But Thanks

Comment: So you should create an interface for each class... Boring but the only way I found.